# "An error has occurred. Please go back or close the browser and try again" when record using jmeter's proxy

Tags: jmeter

I am doing performance testing of a .net application. Whenever we enter url into the browser a browser window opens asking for username and password. After entering that page of site appears.

After setting proxy when I clicked on start button to record script and entered URL to the browser, a message:

> An error has occurred. Please go back or close the browser and try again.

appeared.
Now no login window is getting opened.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is HTTP authentication window. It can be of 3 types: Basic, Digest, NTLM.

JMeter supports only Basic and NTLM authentication. If your site uses it, you can add [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) with correct base url, username and password to your test plan.